# Regex expression in Java Selenium

Tags: java, regex, selenium-webdriver

```
System.out.println("<ChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item='"'(.*)'"'>");


**Expected Output:**    <ChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item="(.*)">
```

The above regex is not working, can someone please help me here.

Thanks,

Satish D

Comment: Try with \"  instead of ' " '

Answer (score 1):

To escape `"` you should use `\"`, but not `'"'`

```
System.out.println("<ChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item=\"(.*)\">");
```

Comment: if i use the above regex the output will be                                                        
    <ChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item=(.*)>                                                               
                                                                                                                 
But am expecting an output like                                                                
    <ChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item="(.*)">

Answer (score 0):

Why not to try like this?

```
String source_string = "<ChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item='\"'(.*)'\"'>";
String target_string = str.replaceAll("'", "");
System.out.println(target_string);
```